# How do you manage 100 virtual servers for inference?

Tags: tensorflow

I need to boot 100 virtual servers and use each for tensorflow model inference for 30 days. What are some tools to do this?

I currently boot the servers using an image, and open two tmux sessions manually. One session is for the model client and the other is for the tensorflow server. I receive a slack notification if any of the server CPUs stop working as a way to know if a server fails (I also manually SSH to debug/restart the server).

Would appreciate any tips!

Comment: What are the virtual servers running on ? I would try to use Ansible or Terraform. But I think your question is off topic here

Comment: Virtual servers are Ubuntu on digital ocean. I looked into Ansible previously but it didn't seem like it provided any debug tools and ways to take control of any server if things go wrong

Comment: I guess you need to be more specific how you want to "take control" and how you can detect if this is necessary. And it would be very helpful if you add these details to your question and if / why you ruled out options (like you did with Ansible)